# Get sibling _id meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a set of buttons that repeat in all my templates. When I click on any of the sections with a class of content_editable I want the buttons next to the clicked section to show. What I've done so far is store the _id of the clicked section in a session but what I'm struggling with is how I will actually show the buttons after the click.

I thought that I could use a helper and get the stored _id and then check that the buttons I want to show is a sibling of the clicked section then compare if the sibling has the same _id as the stored _id. This obviously doesn't work.

//HELPERS

```
UI.registerHelper('copy', function() {
    return ContentCollection.find();
});

UI.registerHelper('toggle', function() {
    var tog = this.nextElementSibling;
    var toggle = tog._id;
    var activeElement = Session.get('activeElement');

    if(activeElement == toggle) {
      return true;
    }
});
```

//EVENTS

```
Template.layoutWrapper.events({

    'click .content__editable': function(e) {
      var clickedContainer = this._id;
      Session.set('activeElement', clickedContainer);
    }

});
```

//TEMPLATES

```
<body>

  {{> layoutWrapper}}

</body>

<template name="layoutWrapper">
    {{> mainLeft}}
    {{> mainRight}}
</template>

<template name="mainLeft">

    <section id="content-left" class="content">
        {{#if toggle}}
            {{> editControls}}
        {{/if}}

        {{#each copy}}
            {{{content}}}
        {{/each}}
    </section>

</template>

<template name="mainRight">

    <section id="content-right" class="content">
        {{#if toggle}}
            {{> editControls}}
        {{/if}}

        {{#each copy}}
            {{{content}}}
        {{/each}}
    </section>

</template>

<template name="editControls">

    <ul class="inline-list">
        <li class="edit">edit</li>
        <li class="save">save</li>
    </ul>

</template>
```

// The output would look like this.

```
<section id="content-right" class="content">
    <ul class="inline-list">
        <li class="edit">edit</li>
        <li class="save">save</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content_editable contentEditable="false">
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: It is hard to understand your requrirement..You have a content editable area and if you click the editable area you want to show a button next to it right? The button is for save the changes I guess

Comment: Yes. every <section> has the set of buttons (edit and save). When I click on the section it must show the buttons. But not all the buttons in each <section> just the buttons that is in the same section that was clicked on. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I edited my question to show what the output of each section would be to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the #if inside the loop:

```
    {{#each copy}}
        {{#if toggle}}
            {{> editControls}}
        {{/if}}
        {{{content}}}
    {{/each}}
```

And leave the toogle helper like this:

```
UI.registerHelper('toggle', function() {
    return Session.equals('activeElement', this._id);
});
```